# Implement Mousewheel in msforms.textbox

Tags: vba, winapi, textbox, mousewheel

I’m trying to implement mousewheel scroll in a large text box. I found Peter Thornton’s code and it works well for frames and userforms (only using it for the former right now), but not for text box because text boxes don’t have a `.ScrollTop` property.

The code I use now isn’t actually a scroll-wheel function. Full code below, but the relevant portion is:

```
If TypeName(mControl) = "TextBox" Then
    If reasonCustKeyPressed Then
        lngSelStart = .SelStart
        .CurLine = .CurLine
        lngOldLinePos = lngSelStart - .SelStart
        reasonCustKeyPressed = False
    End If
    If lParam.Hwnd > 0 Then
        .CurLine = Application.Max(0, .CurLine - cTBOX_SCROLLCHANGE)
    Else
        .CurLine = Application.Min(.LineCount - 1, .CurLine + cTBOX_SCROLLCHANGE)
    End If
    lngSelStart = .SelStart
    If .CurLine < .LineCount - 1 Then
        .CurLine = .CurLine + 1
        .SelStart = .SelStart - 1
    Else
        .SelStart = Len(.Text)
    End If
    lngNewLineLen = .SelStart - lngSelStart
    .SelStart = Application.Min(lngSelStart + lngOldLinePos, lngSelStart + lngNewLineLen)
End If
```

Can anybody give any suggestions on how I could implement actual scroll wheel functionality? One idea I have is to find:

1. Whether the scroll bar was active (the content isn't always long enough to activate it - but don't know how, windows API?).
2. Storing `.SelStart` in a temporary variable
3. Find the top / bottom line somehow (I can't find any property of the textbox like this in documentation)
4. Increase the bottom line / decrease the top line (as appropriate) by setting `.CurLine`
5. Resetting `.SelStart` to the temporary variable (or top / bottom line, if the line stored in the temporary variable is no longer visible).

This isn't ideal either, however, because it doesn't preserve the previous cursor position if you scroll too far. I might be able to work around it by storing the `.SelStart` variable in the module's state and jumping back to it on the `KeyDown` event. There are some really big gaps, however, that I don't really have a good idea of how to fill. Any ideas (for this or other, more elegant solutions)? Thank you in advance.

Full code:

```
Option Explicit
 ' Based on code from Peter Thornton here:
 ' http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7d584120-a929-4e7c-9ec2-9998ac639bea/mouse-scroll-in-userform-listbox-in-excel-2010?forum=isvvba
Private Type POINTAPI
    X                               As Long
    y                               As Long
End Type
Private Type MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT
    pt                              As POINTAPI
    Hwnd                            As Long
    wHitTestCode                    As Long
    dwExtraInfo                     As Long
End Type

Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" _
Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
ByVal lpClassName As String, _
ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function GetWindowLong Lib "user32.dll" _
Alias "GetWindowLongA" ( _
ByVal Hwnd As Long, _
ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" _
Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" ( _
ByVal idHook As Long, _
ByVal lpfn As Long, _
ByVal hmod As Long, _
ByVal dwThreadId As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function CallNextHookEx Lib "user32" ( _
ByVal hHook As Long, _
ByVal nCode As Long, _
ByVal wParam As Long, _
lParam As Any) As Long

Private Declare Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" ( _
ByVal hHook As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function PostMessage Lib "user32.dll" _
Alias "PostMessageA" ( _
ByVal Hwnd As Long, _
ByVal wMsg As Long, _
ByVal wParam As Long, _
ByVal lParam As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function WindowFromPoint Lib "user32" ( _
ByVal xPoint As Long, _
ByVal yPoint As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32.dll" ( _
ByRef lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long

Declare Function GetActiveWindow Lib "user32" () As Long

Private Const WH_MOUSE_LL           As Long = 14
Private Const WM_MOUSEWHEEL         As Long = &H20A
Private Const HC_ACTION             As Long = 0
Private Const GWL_HINSTANCE         As Long = (-6)

Private Const WM_KEYDOWN            As Long = &H100
Private Const WM_KEYUP              As Long = &H101
Private Const VK_UP                 As Long = &H26
Private Const VK_DOWN               As Long = &H28
Private Const WM_LBUTTONDOWN        As Long = &H201

Private Const cFRAME_SCROLLCHANGE   As Long = 20
Private Const cTBOX_SCROLLCHANGE    As Long = 1

Private mLngMouseHook               As Long
Private mControlHwnd                As Long
Private mbHook                      As Boolean
Private lngOldLinePos               As Long
Dim mControl                        As Object


Sub HookFormScroll(oControl As Object, strFormCapt As String)
    Dim lngAppInst                  As Long
    Dim hwndUnderCursor             As Long

    Set mControl = oControl
    hwndUnderCursor = FindWindow("ThunderDFrame", strFormCapt)
    Debug.Print "Form window: " & hwndUnderCursor
    If mControlHwnd <> hwndUnderCursor Then
        UnhookFormScroll
        Debug.Print "Unhook old proc"
        mControlHwnd = hwndUnderCursor
        lngAppInst = GetWindowLong(mControlHwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE)
        If Not mbHook Then
            mLngMouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, AddressOf mouseProc, lngAppInst, 0)
            mbHook = mLngMouseHook <> 0
            If mbHook Then Debug.Print "Form hooked"
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Sub UnhookFormScroll()
    If mbHook Then
        UnhookWindowsHookEx mLngMouseHook
        mLngMouseHook = 0
        mControlHwnd = 0
        mbHook = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Function mouseProc( _
    ByVal nCode As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, _
    ByRef lParam As MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT) As Long
    Dim lngSelStart As Long, lngNewLineLen As Long
    On Error GoTo errH 'Resume Next
    If (nCode = HC_ACTION) Then
        If GetActiveWindow = mControlHwnd Then

            If wParam = WM_MOUSEWHEEL Then
                mouseProc = True
                With mControl
                    If TypeName(mControl) = "Frame" Then
                        If lParam.Hwnd > 0 Then
                            .ScrollTop = Application.Max(0, .ScrollTop - cFRAME_SCROLLCHANGE)
                        Else
                            .ScrollTop = Application.Min(.ScrollHeight - .InsideHeight, .ScrollTop + cFRAME_SCROLLCHANGE)
                        End If
                    Else
                        If TypeName(mControl) = "TextBox" Then
                            If reasonCustKeyPressed Then
                                lngSelStart = .SelStart
                                .CurLine = .CurLine
                                lngOldLinePos = lngSelStart - .SelStart
                                reasonCustKeyPressed = False
                            End If
                            If lParam.Hwnd > 0 Then
                                .CurLine = Application.Max(0, .CurLine - cTBOX_SCROLLCHANGE)
                            Else
                                .CurLine = Application.Min(.LineCount - 1, .CurLine + cTBOX_SCROLLCHANGE)
                            End If
                            lngSelStart = .SelStart
                            If .CurLine < .LineCount - 1 Then
                                .CurLine = .CurLine + 1
                                .SelStart = .SelStart - 1
                            Else
                                .SelStart = Len(.Text)
                            End If
                            lngNewLineLen = .SelStart - lngSelStart
                            .SelStart = Application.Min(lngSelStart + lngOldLinePos, lngSelStart + lngNewLineLen)
                        End If
                    End If
                End With
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If

    End If
    mouseProc = CallNextHookEx( _
    mLngMouseHook, nCode, wParam, ByVal lParam)
    Exit Function
errH:
    UnhookFormScroll
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

[Daniel Pineault's code](https://www.devhut.net/2014/01/22/ms-access-enable-mouse-wheel-scrolling-of-text-box/) worked fine for me. It's one module and a few lines of code to put on your form.

Comment: Thank you @ndemou, but the tool this was working in has been replaced by a cloud solution so testing and troubleshooting to confirm the solution wouldn't be worth the return on investment. Actually, what's the SO etiquette for a situation like this?

Comment: @PKB, don't worry: the way SO works, not accepting it, isn't really an issue. Everyone can up-vote if it works for them. In the end good _and_ _interesting_ answers will rise. Emphasis on interesting because Access was great some 20 years ago but it has hardly improved since then.